# Right way to show proportional divs with images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I am trying to achieve this layout.
I have parent div (lightgray) and I have two divs inside it.

Left div (gray) have square image inside it. Image should cover all div. Right div have some text label and 3 buttons. This buttons are inside button group div and in portrait mode on iPhone sometimes they need to be placed not in one line but one under another.

What css rules or bootstrap classes I should use?

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn to use the Bootstrap grid system. You shall create a container with columns inside it. You can make them display differently for each screen size. For example this div will be full width on extra small devices (screen width <768px) and half of the width on medium sizes desktops (≥992px).

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Hello</div>
```

You shall read about the grid system and everything will be clear.

[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Also, use the Responsive utilities for showing/hiding elements for different screen sizes:

[Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Bootstrap media querys to achieve that

Have a look [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/):

Answer (score 0):

*"Sometimes they need to be placed not in one line but one under another"*

Aren't you able to use the combination of a **CSS media query** to justify what pixel you want the code to change at and then add a `display: block;` code to make them elements go underneath eachother ?

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .whatever {
    display: block;
  }
```